# asp.net webapi unhandled exception behavior

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Using Asp.net WebApi 2, looking to understand how exceptions are handled by the frameworks.

When an exception occurs on the server while servicing a request, it looks like there is logic that translates the exception automatically to a 500 response and swallows the exception.

1. Are there any 'critical' type of exceptions which are treated differently ? (and result in the termination of the process? e.g. OutOfMemoryException)
2. Is it correct to assume this exception swallowing behavior is only true for a thread currently servicing a request? E.g. If I started a background thread (almost always bad) which throws an exception, the process will terminate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the answers below:

1. If the server runs out of memory, certainly the whole server will be brought down. Therefore, the API won't be available for request.

In most other cases, a 500 Response will be returned for unhandled exceptions, except a **HttpResponseException**. In that case, the status depends on the values defined by developers. More from here http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/exception-handling

1. If a unhandled exception is thrown in a background thread, then it will be swallowed.

It is a good practice to have a global exception handler for exceptions thrown outside of a controller, namely:

- Exceptions thrown from controller constructors.
- Exceptions thrown from message handlers.
- Exceptions thrown during routing.
- Exceptions thrown during response content serialization .

Using the following tutorial http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/web-api-global-error-handling